# Entity Framework list of objects contains list of object lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

Following scenario:

```
public class User{
    public virtual ICollection<MediaItem> MediaItems { get; set; }
}

public enum eMediaItemGenre
{
    [Display(Name = "Pop")]
    POP = 0,
    [Display(Name = "Other")]
    OTHER = 11
}

public class MediaItem
{
    public virtual ICollection<MediaItemGenre> Genres { get; set; }
}

public class MediaItemGenre
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public eMediaItemGenre Genre { get; set; }

    public Int32 MediaItemId { get; set; }

    public virtual MediaItem MediaItem { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to do the following: I have a `MediaItem` and I would like to find `MediaItems` that share the same `Genre`.

I did it this way:

```
List<MediaItem> lItems = ltCOntext.MediaItems.Where(x => x.Genres.Any(y => pGenres.Contains(y))).ToList();
```

but I get an error

> Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: Why don't you have primary key in `MediaItem` and `User`?

Comment: I do. I just removed all the properties on here so the code wont get too long.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to compare complex types in database with a list of complex types in memory, this is not possible. What I suggest doing is converting your `pGenres` to a list of `int` by using projection:

```
List<int> pGenresId = pGenres.Select(p => p.Id).ToList();
```

Then you can use your query:

```
List<MediaItem> lItems = ltCOntext.MediaItems
         .Where(x => x.Genres.Select(g => g.Id).Any(y => pGenresId.Contains(y))).ToList();
```

Now Linq-to-entities can convert this into a query by putting the `int`'s of the `Id`'s in the queries.

Comment: Wasn't exactly what I needed but this is what got the idea through to me.

Answer (score 1):

And if you try this variant :

```
 ICollection<MediaItemGenre> pGenres = mediaItem.Genres;

 List<MediaItem> lItems = 
                 ltCOntext.MediaItems
                          .Where(m => m.Genres
                                       .Any(g => 
                                            mediaItem.Genres
                                           .Select(c=>c.Id).Contains(g.Id))).ToList();
```